# problem with installing ubuntu along with windows 7

Tags: system-installation

while installing from an  usb,the process is continuing till i get an option of "Install ubuntu inside windows".When i click ok the process get stuck and windows is getting started.how can i resolve this?

Comment: However I have Ubuntu 13.10 alongside with Windows 7. Just starting I can choose the operating system selected.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to install alongside windows or whave ubuntu contained within? I don't believe wubi is supported any longer for 13.10 and up, however you may get it to work with some tinkering.

You can try:

1. Installing ubuntu alongside windows to a seperate partition.
2. Running ubuntu from a virtual drive within windows using software such as virtualbox.

Good luck.